# Applying Multiple Rewrite Conditions with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have two requirements with the .**htaccess** file.

First one is to apply "/index.php" part for all urls as a prefix,so it wont need to add the same part manually for all the URLs in my codeignitor project.This part works fine.

The second requirement is I need to **block direct access to my .PHP** files and for that, I'm using another rewrite condition but its not working and I cant figure out what is wrong with my following code.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```